# How does AWS know which DynamoDB database to connect to from the iOS api?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

I have two separate AWS accounts, one for production and one for development. I use DynamoDB, S3 and Elastic Beanstalk. I switch between the two accounts using an id and password on the AWS website, different AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID/AWS_SECRET_KEY on an Elastic Beanstalk servlet and Cognito identities from my iOS app. This has been working fine up until recently when I tried to set the iOS app to use the development AWS account. This has worked fine in the past, the only difference is the CognitoIdentityPoolId in the following code.

```
    AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:CognitoRegionType identityPoolId:CognitoIdentityPoolId];
    AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:DefaultServiceRegionType credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

However my iOS app continues to access the DynamoDB in the Production account even though it has the CognitoIdentitytPoolID for the Development account. I have deleted the app and its data from the iPhone (and tried same on simulator) and cleaned the project. I have double checked that CognitoIdentitytPoolID has changed to the Development one.

I see that one can now set up roles to allow users to access resources in different accounts but I am doing nothing sophisticated like that - I have not even set up IAM users on either account (atm security is not an issue). I simply have IAM roles (CognitoXXXUnauthRole) with the policies necessary to access DynamoDB and S3. These policies do not have an full arn for DynamoDB so that doesnt appear to be be why the accounts are not changing for the ios app.

So my question boils down to 'how does AWS know which DynamoDB database to connect to from the iOS api?"

Comment: I developed an ios app in swift almost two years ago so I am a bit rusty here. I created a role and attached a policy to this role. This policy gives access to the specific dynamodb instance which I think you need to do. I wrote a guide at https://gnome.no/2016/05/amazon-cognito-and-facebook-login/ which you can look at. The relevant section is from "Click on Roles in the left column ...". If useful I can try to write it into an answer. HTH.

Comment: Thanks kometen, will check that out

Comment: I have experience with iOS and have experience with AWS, not used them together yet though. You should show the code how your app is set up to communicate with AWS, in particular with DynamoDB. One potential issue might be that you already mentioned "These policies do not have an full arn for DynamoDB". That means that in the context of your Role you have multiple DynamoDB tables called "YourTableName" and it might simply be impossible for AWS to choose the correct instance unless you set up the roles correctly

Comment: As you can see from my answer I have resolved this, thanks kometen, luk2302, in case you are interested the policies just give permissions to access resources (as I had thought), they don't specify which resources *to* access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this was simple - my hard coded CognitoIdentityPoolId was being ignored. There is one in the Info.plist that gets used instead. I now have two Info.plist files that get swapped depending on whether I am in debug mode or not. Not particularly convenient as sandbox/production is not synonymous with Debug/Release but will tackle that another time...